# Math Question - Find unknown variable with equations

Tags: arithmetic

Three-digit numbers *P, Q,* and *R*, *QQP* and *PQQ* are formed using the single digits P,
Q and R such that:

*PQR + 2 = PQQ*

and

*PQR * 2 = QQP*

Determine all possible combinations of values of P, Q and R that satisfy the two
equations.

Here is my work so far:

What we know:

```
R+2=Q, PQ remains the same meaning there were no carrying needed. R+2<=9

The second equation, R*2=P. R cannot be 0 as anything multiplied by 0 is 0.
```

What we know about R:

```
Ranges from 1 – 7
```

What we know about P:

```
Cannot be 0 as it is in the hundred digits. 
P*2 = Q
```

What we know about Q:

```
Q*2 = the first digit of QR.
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you simplify any of the equations?

Comment: There really aren't that many things to try here.

Comment: Well I have tried trial and error, we know each variable has to be in between 0 - 9, and P cannot be 0. This strategy isn't going so well, there are 10*10*10 possibilities here.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The first equation gives us $ R + 2 = Q$.

**Hint:** The second equation then gives us $199 P - 4 = 88Q$

> Do some work here, yes you.

Hence conclude that $P = 4, Q = 9, R = 7$.

Comment: I have a question, where did you get 199 and 88 from? And how does a *2 becomes a -4?

Comment: @Andrew Show your work by writing out the equation, then tell me where you're stuck.

Comment: I have added all my work so far with the hints you've provided. Thanks

Comment: @Andrew The second equation is $2\times (100P + 10 Q + R) = 100Q + 10 Q + P$, just as the first equation is $ 100 P + 10 Q + R + 2 = 100P + 10 Q + Q$.

Comment: I see what you did there, I did not think of it that way. Thanks for your help

Comment: This is why it's helpful to write out what you are thinking, so that others can respond accordingly.